# Manipulating and saving local Json file in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am creating an app in react where I can import a local json file , change its values and save it back. What would be the best way to do it?

Is there a library to import local JSON files? If yes, what is the difference b/w the library and a simple `import from "./local.json"` statement?

And what be the best way to download it locally instead of having a `<a>` tag with the download attribute?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

When you develop front-end apps you should start thinking in terms of "my app is running within the browser, what the browser could do?"

Could the browser load a local JSON file? The answer is yes, but the JSON file needs to be served within your front end project folder.

Could the browser write a local JSON file? I don't think so.

Could the browser load a local JSON file everywhere in the user's machine? No, because of security.

If you want to load/save data locally, you could use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to achieve that.

---

On the other hand, if you work with a backend app, then yes, you could access every file/folder in the server.